# force close at cursor line!

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hy!
I'm trying to create an application that looks for gps data that was stored in SQlite database.
But I'm facing a problem:
I built an DbAdapter class that creates my database and now I'm trying from another class to get an cursor over my all data,using this function:

```
public Cursor fetchAllData() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_LONGITUDE,KEY_LATITUDE,KEY_COUNTRY,KEY_TOWN,KEY_STREET}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

Now,I'm creating an instance of DbAdapter in my new class,but I get forceclose when I insert this line:Cursor c=db.fetchAllData();

The class that creates my database looks like this:

```
package test.android;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class CoordonateDbAdapter {


    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_LONGITUDE= "longitude";
    public static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "latitude";
    public static final String KEY_COUNTRY= "country";
    public static final String KEY_TOWN= "town";
    public static final String KEY_STREET = "street";

    private static final String TAG = "CoordonateDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table car1 (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + "longitude text not null, latitude text not null," +
                   "country text not null,town text not null,street text not null);";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gps";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "masini";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
    public CoordonateDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }
    public CoordonateDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
    public long insertData(String longitude, String latitude, String country, String town, String street) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, longitude);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LATITUDE, latitude);
        initialValues.put(KEY_COUNTRY, country);
        initialValues.put(KEY_TOWN, town);
        initialValues.put(KEY_STREET, street);

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
    public boolean deleteData(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
   public Cursor fetchAllData() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_LONGITUDE,KEY_LATITUDE,KEY_COUNTRY,KEY_TOWN,KEY_STREET}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
    public Cursor fetchData(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] 
                    {KEY_ROWID, KEY_LONGITUDE,KEY_LATITUDE,KEY_COUNTRY,KEY_TOWN,KEY_STREET}, 
                     KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
    public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String longitude, String latitude,String country, String town,String street) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, longitude);
        args.put(KEY_LATITUDE, latitude);
        args.put(KEY_COUNTRY, country);
        args.put(KEY_TOWN, town);
        args.put(KEY_STREET, street);

        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    public List<String> selectAll() {

       List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
       Cursor cursor = this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { "longitude"},

         null, null, null, null, "name desc");

       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

          do {

             list.add(cursor.getString(0));

          } while (cursor.moveToNext());

       }
       if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {

          cursor.close();

       }

       return list;

    }
}
```

---

And the class that retrieves the gps data is like this:

```
package test.android;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class screen_database extends Activity{

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.screen_database);
           CoordonateDbAdapter db = new CoordonateDbAdapter(this); 
          db.open();
          long id;
      //    id= db.insertData("-36.2", "125","Romania","Cluj","Zorilor");
      //    db.insertData("44", "55","Romania","Iasi","Alexandru Ioan Cuza");
       //   List<String> names = db.selectAll();
           Cursor c=db.fetchAllData();

         /*  if (c.moveToFirst())
            {
                do {          
                  //  DisplayTitle(c);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }*/
         //   c.close();

        }

      /*  public void DisplayTitle(Cursor c)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, 
                    "longitude: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
                    "latitude: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                    "country: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
                    "town:  " + c.getString(3),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
        }*/ 
}
//}
```

You can see lots of lines that are comments because I get force close when I'm asking for a Cursor,so I tried to keep it as simple.
Do I need any permissions to work with cursors,becuase I looked on the internet and all the line code looks like mine?!
Another problem is that my application is quite big,and I'm accesing this classes from other classes....a long row of classes until I get to query from the Sqlite.
I would really apreciate if you would help me,it might be something simple but I can't figure it out what it is.Thank you!!!

Comment: PLease help me if u know where is wrong cause I'm out of ideas...and is really urgent for me to fix this:)

Comment: `mDB` is definitely not null at the point where you're calling `db.fetchAllData()`?

Comment: well,usually I have the lines above working...

Comment: id= db.insertData("-36.2", "125","Romania","Cluj","Zorilor");
       db.insertData("44", "55","Romania","Iasi","Alexandru Ioan Cuza");...in the comment posted by me are comments,but in my code are working,so I should have something  in it:)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the line with a try/catch block?  What are the details of the exception?

Comment: No,I haven't.The details-usually this intent works cause I've tried with something simple-a view text,which is displayed....but when I'm trying to get the cursor it give me force close-I'm sure you know what that is.

Comment: What is weird is that these two classes are copyed/updated from the internet and they work perfectly if i have only the two of them.But when I try to insert these two inside my project-it fails.As I said,I have other classes before these two...I pass through a few intents till I get here.This might be a problem?I modified the  Manifest file with the order of the classes so I don't think the problem is coming from there.Thank you for trying to help me,I'm really desperate

Comment: Assuming you're using Eclipse to debug this, what information is the logcat giving you about the exception?

Comment: Is the first time when I use this,it gave me lots of lines.Next to errors it says that:"Databse Error inserting longitude=44 town=Iasi street=Alexandru Ioan Cuza country=Romania"...that means that I couldn't insert those things in my database and is empty...but why?The inserting method used is ok,I think:-S

Comment: And I found error also next to the other insert line!Another error was thread attach file!Sorry for spelling you like this,but I never used this and I'm really new to android!

Comment: can you post the logcat output?

Comment: The logcat should give you a call stack at the point of the exception.  Basically, when the code crashes you'll need to hit f8 a couple of times for this to appear in the logcat.  That will tell you what's happening.  Other than that, you need to single step through your code.  Make sure the functions are being called as expected and that they're working as expected.  Single step into fetchAllData and make sure mDB is set as expected.  Basically, the quickest way for you to find the problem is to debug it.

Comment: 03-26 04:59:21.356: DEBUG/dalvikvm(295): VM cleaning up
03-26 04:59:21.387: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(295): ERROR: thread attach failed
03-26 04:59:21.832: DEBUG/dalvikvm(295): LinearAlloc 0x0 used 623012 of 5242880 (11%)
03-26 04:59:21.997: DEBUG/ActivityManager(52): Uninstalling process test.android
03-26 04:59:22.346: WARN/ResourceType(52): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f0700e5
03-26 04:59:22.346: WARN/ResourceType(52): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020031
03-26 04:59:22.346: WARN/ResourceType(52): Resources don't contain package for resource

Comment: Ok,I'll try to learn the debugger.....I'll be back:)...thank u

Comment: And don't know if u are there,but after all it seems that there are really some problems with my insert methods,but I can't really figure out what it is:)

Answer (score 0):

first try to access directly by copying

```
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_LONGITUDE,KEY_LATITUDE,KEY_COUNTRY,KEY_TOWN,KEY_STREET}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

instead of calling it by method.
If that works, check if curser is available in the method.
If it is, try to reduce the SQLQuery like

```
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_LONGITUDE}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

and add more columns step by step.